# Cannot get js variable inside php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Cannot get `a` inside `msg.php`

```
$('#click01').click(function(){
  var a = 14;
  $.ajax({
    url : 'msg.php',
    type : 'post',
    data : {a:a}
    }).done(function() {
      window.location='msg.php';
    })
});
```

msg.php

```
var_dump($_POST['a']); // NULL, but i need `14`
```

Comment: How do you know it is NULL?

Comment: try to print $_REQUEST

Comment: @putvande, using `var_dump` - `NULL` is written on display

Comment: it surely sending 14 from ajax

Comment: try using echo or print instead of var_dump

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting `null` because after the AJAX call is done you send the user to `msg.php` where `$_POST` is empty again.

When you do :

```
    $('#click01').click(function () {
     var a = 14;
     $.ajax({
         url: 'msg.php',
         type: 'post',
         data: {
             a: a
         }
     }).done(function (data) {
         alert(data);
     })
 });
```

You will see it works and you get 14.

I see no good reason to first use AJAX to POST something and then on success send the user to that same page.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad concet of ajax request.

```
$('#click01').click(function(){
  var a = 14;
  $.ajax({
    url : 'msg.php',
    type : 'post',
    data : {a:a}
    }).done(function(data) {
      // data= var_dump($_POST['a'])
      alert(data)
    })
});
```

In var data you have the result of ajax request, but if you redirect to msg.php no have the variable

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are checking the ajax return, and not the return of the `window.location='msg.php';` ?

Try this:

```
$('#click01').click(function(){
  var a = 14;
  $.ajax({
    url : 'msg.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {'a':a},
    success: function(r) { alert(r); }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// Instead of var_dump($_POST['a']) at msg.php use:- 
// extract($_POST);  echo $a;

$('document').ready(function(){ var a = 14;

```
    $.ajax({
      url  : "msg.php",
      type : 'post',
      data : {a:a}
      }).done(function(data) {
          alert(data);

      });
});
```